# Best practice for preventing duplicate AggregateCreated events

Tags: java, cqrs, axon

I have the following (Axon) Aggregate :

```
@Aggregate
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Car{
  @AggregateIdentifier
  private String id;

  @CommandHandler
  public Car(CreateCar command){
    apply( new CarCreated(command.getId()) );
  }

  @EventSourcingHandler
  public void carCreated(CarCreated event) {
    this.id = event.getId();
  }

}
```

And I can create the car by submitting a `CreateCar` command with a specific id, causing a `CarCreated` event. That is great.

However, if I send another `CreateCar` command, with the same Id, the command cannot be validated by the aggregate (that the given id already exists). Subsequently it will simply fire a new `CarCreated` event. Which is a lie.

What would be the best approach to make sure the `CreateCar` command fails if the car already exists?

Naturally I could first check the repository, but this won't prevent race conditions...

Comment: use UUID or generate id in database

Comment: and how does this prevent two CarCreated events?

Comment: The same create event with the same aggregate identifier can't be saved in the event store, so this transaction should fail at the database level, and be rolled back. I suspect you're using UUIDs for the aggregate identifier, and actually want the aggregates to also have a unique constraint on another identifier. In this case, as far as axon is concerned, you're creating a new unique aggregate, that just happens to have an identical payload to another one. You will have to solve this with a lock and read on a query table.

Comment: This is usually handled using optimistic concurrency. When emitting an event to your storage technology you should send the expected event index along with the event. For your created event that would be 0 (for 0-based systems). Your storage technology hopefully supports this and will check that the event with index 0 has not already been stored and fail otherwise.

You get the current event index from hydrating your aggregate. See, when you get the events for your aggregate (before you handle the command) you simply count the number of events and use that count as the expected event index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, if I send another CreateCar command, with the same Id, the command cannot be validated by the aggregate (that the given id already exists). Subsequently it will simply fire a new CarCreated event. Which is a lie.

Axon actually takes care of this for you. When an aggregate publishes an event, it is not published to other components immediately. It is staged in the Unit of Work, awaiting completion of the handler execution.
After handler execution, a number of "prepare commit" handlers are invoked. One of these stores the aggregate (which is a no-op when using event sourcing), the other is publication of the events (within the scope of a transaction).

Depending on whether you use Event Sourcing or not, either adding the Aggregate instance to the persistent storage will fail (duplicate key), or the publication of the creation event will fail (duplicate aggregate identifier + sequence number).

Comment: Hopefully you guys will implement https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/653 soon :P

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the best approach to make sure the CreateCar command fails if the car already exists?  Naturally I could first check the repository, but this won't prevent race conditions...

There is no magic.

If you are going to avoid racy writes, then you need either to acquire a lock on the data store, or you need a data store with `compare and swap` semantics.

With a lock, you have a guarantee that no conflicting updates will occur between your *read* of the data in the store and your subsequent write.

```
lock = lock_for_id id
lock.acquire
Try:
    Option[Car] root = repository.load id
    switch root {

        case None:
            Car car = createCar ...
            repository.store car  

        case Some(car):
            // deal with the fact that the car has already been created   

    }
Finally:
    lock.release
```

You'd like to have a lock for each aggregate, but creating locks has the same racy conditions that creating aggregates does.  So you will likely end up with something like a [coarse grained lock](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/coarseGrainedLock.html) to restrict access to the operation.

With compare-and-swap, you push the contention management toward the data store.  Instead of sending the store a [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4), you are sending a [conditional PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3).

```
    Option[Car] root = repository.load id
    switch root {

        case None:
            Car car = createCar ...
            repository.replace car None

        case Some(car):
            // deal with the fact that the car has already been created   

    }
```

We don't need the locks any more, because we are describing precisely for the store the precondition (eg [If-None-Match: *](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.2)) that needs to be satisfied.

The compare and swap semantic is commonly supported by event stores; "appending" new events onto a stream is done by crafting a query that identifies the expected position of the tail pointer, with specially encoded values to identify cases where the stream is expected to be created (for example, Event Store support an [ExpectedVersion.NoStream](https://eventstore.org/docs/dotnet-api/writing-to-a-stream/index.html) semantic).